# Getting rid of a virus

Tags: firefox, malware, clamav

So I know Linux isn't supposed to get viruses, but it really looks like I have one. A tab popped in firefox saying an update was required and it wouldn't let me close it (it did not look like a legitimate firefox update), with repeated pop up messages saying information would need to be resent- everytime I selected cancel, it came up again. I was also unable to open the software centre.

I assumed the problem was firefox-specific so used purge to uninstall. At first it seemed like it worked, but when I restarted my computer firefox was still there. I tried to run purge again, but it said there was nothing to delete. So I tried to delete the program files, which seems to have  gotten rid of firefox, except I still can't open the software center so I assume there's still a problem.

I ran clamscan and it said there's no infected files

> Known viruses: 6354850
>   Engine version: 0.99.2
>   Scanned directories: 37159
>   Scanned files: 146987
>   Infected files: 0
>   Total errors: 21365
>   Data scanned: 8522.39 MB
>   Data read: 9700.28 MB (ratio 0.88:1)
>   Time: 1658.820 sec (27 m 38 s)

Next steps?

Comment: Hm sorry this is strange. Anyway it is a huge mistake to think Linux where `not supposed to get viruses`. It is just not that common because the philosophy of strictly seperating user and `root` usually protects you quite well against any system harming stuff.

Comment: Sounds like a hijacking of your Firefox profile. Your profile is stored in /home, and cannot be touched by apt (even 'purge'). But *you* can delete it. Warning: It will erase your bookmarks and auto-logins, too.

Comment: @user535733 .. you are wrong, first the profile don't live in /homebut in /home/<UserName>/.mozilla, second apt si run with superuser rights (sudo) so it CAN touch the users profile .. but it propably won't.

Comment: To clarify, `sudo apt purge firefox` does NOT touch the users profile, which can be in multiple places in users home directory, therefore to have a one catch all command it would be `rm ~/.mozilla ~/.cache/mozilla ~/.config/mozilla ~/.local/share/mozilla`. Dont worry if it says that some of the files are have not been present, this just means there where none.

Comment: @Beth You could try to start Firefox from a terminal `firefox -P`, this opens the profile editor, create there a new profile and start from this for initial testing if this resolves your problem. Please report back to us.

Answer (score 6):

First, welcome to Ubuntu.

Second, not every problem you might encounter is a "Virus", there are lots of different cracks.

Third, clamav did not identify a virus

> Infected files: 0

And last, the behavior you describe sounds more like a browser hijack rather than a virus

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_hijacking or similar for additional information.

Removal sort of depends on the hijack, but, in general, the easiest is to simply remove your mozilla profile.

**From @Videonauth**

You can test this theory with by starting Firefox with a fresh profile (from the command line):

```
firefox -P
```

This opens the profile editor, create there a new profile and start from this for initial testing if this resolves your problem.

If yes start again with the above command and start your old profile once more. This will give you an opportunity to export your bookmarks and passwords (from your old profile; probably good idea is to use Firefox-Sync) before deleting your profile.

**This command will delete bookmarks and saved passwords !! Export your passwords and/or bookmarks if you wish to keep them before you run this command**

```
rm ~/.mozilla ~/.cache/mozilla ~/.config/mozilla ~/.local/share/mozilla
```

In the future, take care what sites you visit and you might want to install some malware extensions in Firefox such NoScript, AdBlock, uMatrix just to name a few.

See also https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-search-hijacking

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Opening Firefox in a new profile means that Firefox now works fine, but I'm still unable to open the software center?

Comment: @Beth start a new question for software center.

Comment: does that mean it's a separate issue? Because it started at the same time as the pop up thing which makes it seem like it's a symptom of the same problem and the virus/hijack/issue is still there?

Comment: @Beth Although it happened at the same time, I don't see how they would be related. There is nothing to suggest you have any sort of virus .